# React Router and passing props to other component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-props, react-state

I have a button in one component and on click I want to go to other component and pass to this component the state.

It's something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import AddNewQuestionPage from 'AddNewQuestionPage';

class AddQuestions extends Component {
  state = {
    questions: []
  };

  routeChange = () => {
    let path = `/admin/add-new-question`;
    this.props.history.push(path);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
       <button onClick={this.routeChange}>
          Add new question
       </button>
       <BrowserRouter>
        <Route exact={true} path='/admin/add-new-question' component={AddNewQuestionPage}/>
       </BrowserRouter>
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

And it doesn't work. On click I go to add-new-question url but the component AddNewQuestionPage doesn't render. It works if I put Route not in AddQuestions component, but in App component. It's the main component of the whole app and using Switch, there are set also other routes.

However I don't know how I can pass the state questions to AddNewQuestionPage component if it's rendered from App component? I can't just do:

```
<Route path='/admin/add-new-question' render={(props) => <AddNewQuestionPage {...props} questions={questions} />
```

because it doesn't know what is "questions". Lifting the state up to the main component doesn't seem a good solution for me. I was searching and I can't find how to do it...

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `this` keyword on the question you're passing to the component.

So something like this

```js
<Route path='/admin/add-new-question' render={(props) => <AddNewQuestionPage {...props} questions={this.state.questions} />
```

Comment: Thank you, now it seems to work, however if I do console.log(this.props.questions) in AddNewQuestionPage component, it is undefined.

Comment: Are you sure you passed the props in a constructor and super?

Comment: I don't use constructor and super in this project at all. I do like described here: https://hackernoon.com/the-constructor-is-dead-long-live-the-constructor-c10871bea599 However now I tried also with constructor and it doesn't changed anything. When I do console.log(this.props) there is questions prop but it has value undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to use react-router dom is :

1. Always make  as a parent component for all.
2. The best way to change the path by clicking on a sort of component (button ...) is You label

Please check this guide out : https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In my app, the App component is a parent for all. I don't understand what are you talking about as "You label" :) Can you explain it? I was reading documentation but I couldn't find there the solution.